# Incoming Mail in Sharepoint

Tags: smtp

Our Incoming mail are not posting to lists. Some sites are able to get the incoming mail but they are different on databases. Some sites which are on different content database incoming mail is not posting to the lists. All the sites have same App server and web server. I can see incoming e-mail in Drop folder if I set the setting as save the e-mail in Drop folder.

Can somebody help? I am new to Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: Are all of these sites (both working and non) on the same Web Application, i.e. http://someUrl.domain.com or on different web apps?

Comment: Both of them are the same web application.

Comment: Was this site migrated to SharePoint 2010 from 2007 recently?

Comment: No its been more than 6 months. All other sites are getting e-mail its just one site which is not working. I just tried to created a new site with same database and the e-mail is posted to this new site. Is there any site setting which I should be looking at?

Comment: I have tried the deleting the settings and still it didn't work. I tried to create another discussion and set the e-mail setting and it is not working on this particulatr site.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug where, under certain conditions (usually related to 2007-2010 upgrade or when a server name changes) a list will become 'stuck' where it cannot receive email.  The fix is fortunately extremely simple and painless :

- Go to the list properties and select 'Incoming Email Settings'
- Copy the current email address to someplace else, like Notepad++
- Change the 'Allow this list to receive e-mail' to 'No' and hit 'OK'
- Go back into the incoming email settings for the list
- set the 'Allow this list to receive e-mail' to 'Yes' and paste the
  original address back in and hit ok.
- Go back into the incoming email settings and make a note of the FULL email address required.  Usually this is something like 'listname@sharepoint.domain.com'
- Send email to the address as it appears in SharePoint

If that doesn't work, check the permissions on the list and make sure that whoever is testing the email functionality has at least 'contribute' permissions to the list.  Either that or enable the 'Accept e-mail messages from any sender' option, though this is only advisable in a controlled Intranet environment.

Comment: have tried the deleting the settings and still it didn't work. I tried to create another discussion and set the e-mail setting and it is not working on this particulatr site.

Comment: Is there anything in the SharePoint logs around the time that the email arrives in the Drop folder?

Comment: No I don't see anything in the logs too...........Apparently all the sites are working fine. It is just one site and then its child sites.

Comment: The user that is being used to send the emails has 'Contribute' permissions to the list, right?

Comment: Yes it does. Infact it has full control

Comment: You might need to work with your Exchange Administrators to make sure that the emails to those lists are being delivered to the SMTP server on the farm.  I can't think why they wouldn't if others are being delivered but it could be an overzealous filters/spam/junk in the mix.

Comment: When I change the setting in the List to save the e-mail in the drop box it get saved in the drop box. So it is reaching to the server and after that point I am not sure what happens. But If i am not saving the e-mail in the drop box it doesn't get saved. It is not getting stuck in Drop box too.